# How to access sql server 2008 R2 from C# ClickOnce application over a network

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking, clickonce

I've a clickOnce C# application that works fine on a standalone computer. i wanted to use the application over the network but the system fails to connect to the sql server (SQL SERVER 2008 R2) and throws an exception. I've created a user on the sql server and assigned it on the connection string of the application. However, the problem still persists. Any help please?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting. Is the server reachable from the other machine? Is there a firewall in the way? Are you trying to use named pipes and the browsing service is off?

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string on your app

check:

[Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Configure your SQL server security as  sql server and windows authentication mode.

Make sure its instance is running.

Create sql server authentication login if your app will be use on network.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried all possible ways but didn't work. The SQL SERVER is running on Window 7 and the client machine is with XP. Does it have any effect?